# Correcting the names in nlp

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a dataset where lot of names are written like man1sh instead of manish, vikas as v1kas.

How can one correct these names in nlp?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In python, 'v1kas'.replace('1', 'i') would do the trick.  Or is your question, how to identify strings with numbers in them?  Or is it, how do I identify strings with numbers in them, and then write a program smart enough to replace those numbers with the correct letter?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Deep Neural Network based spell correction https://medium.com/@majortal/deep-spelling-9ffef96a24f6 this method is the state of the art method at the moment. Here is the code https://github.com/MajorTal/DeepSpell and some one already made an improvement over it https://hackernoon.com/improving-deepspell-code-bdaab1c5fb7e.I am not able to find the paper but there is also a paper published that does character level deep neural network for edit distance with good results and a public dataset.

For the above methods, like for all Machine Learning solutions, you need data for training. If you don't have data for your case then the old simple edit distance methods http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html are the only way.